# Checking if A is superclass of B in Python

Tags: python, reflection, superclass

```
class p1(object): pass
class p2(p1): pass
```

So p2 is the subclass of p1.  Is there a way to find out programmatically that p1 is [one of] the superclass[es] of p2 ?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes, there is way. You can use a [issubclass](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#issubclass) function.

As follows:

```
class p1(object):pass
class p2(p1):pass

issubclass(p2, p1)
```

Comment: Attention: `issubclass(A, A)` evaluates to `True`.  This may not be intuitive. At least to me, it seems obvious that a class is **not** its own subclass. `issubclass` should have been called `istypeofclass`.

Comment: @limiacs, for me who thinks classes as `set`, this doesn't bother me. A is a subset of A.

Comment: @VineetMenon true, that is most likely the reason, but programming languages are not only meant for mathematicians, and it is definitely not intuitive for most people to think that a class is a subclass of itself.

Comment: how to evaluate to true only if subclass but not itself? see first comment

Comment: @qrtLs, if A should be a true subclass of B you can do this: `issubclass(A,B) and not A == B`

Answer (score 46):

using <class>.__bases__ seems to be what you're looking for...

```
>>> class p1(object): pass
>>> class p2(p1): pass
>>> p2.__bases__
(<class '__main__.p1'>,)
```

Comment: @nikow, right... but the issue with issubclass() is that it requires giving a class to compare against, whereas __ bases __ will just give you the superclass(es) outright.  Both solutions can be useful depending on the circumstances.

Comment: For my question, issubclass() was the better answer, but this answer is also appreciated.

Comment: `__bases__` will only give you the direct parents (the ones in the parenthesis of the class definition), while issubclass checks the entire chain of inheritance.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on what you're trying to do, the "mro" method can also be useful.

Answer (score 5):

I think you meant to use "class" instead of "def".. :) Anyway, try `p2.__bases__`